# Python tkinter GIL crashing issue with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, gil

So iam making a hand recognition project to control the volume with your fingers. And it all worked then i wanted to add a separate tkinter gui along side the hand tracking which i can control stuff like adding a button to show/not show the fps and other stuff. However when i click the tkinter gui and click the fps tracker button i added it just freezes and crashed, no clue what the cause is.

Hope some can help! thanks alot

Full code [here](https://github.com/mathewsjoyy/OpenCV_HandDetection)

console error output:

```py
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: initialized

Thread 0x00001994 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 316 in wait
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 574 in wait
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 245 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00002480 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 316 in wait
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 574 in wait
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 199 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00000830 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 312 in wait
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 574 in wait
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_timeout.py", line 43 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00003150 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 219 in _read_line
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 237 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000303c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 316 in wait
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\queue.py", line 180 in get
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 382 in _on_run
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_daemon_thread.py", line 46 in run
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 908 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00000734 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\OpenCV_HandDetection\handVolumeControl.py", line 152 in handDetection
  File "c:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\OpenCV_HandDetection\handVolumeControl.py", line 45 in __startDetection
  File "c:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\OpenCV_HandDetection\handVolumeControl.py", line 50 in run_app
  File "c:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\Python\OpenCV_HandDetection\handVolumeControl.py", line 158 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87 in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97 in _run_module_code
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268 in run_path
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285 in run_file
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444 in main
  File "c:\Users\mathe\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.8.1102490946\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87 in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\mathe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197 in _run_module_as_main
```

MAIN FILE `handVolumeControl.py`

```py
"""
A hand tracking script which can help to control the volume bar
Python 3.9.0
"""

# Import necessary libraries
import HandTrackingModule as htm
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
import math
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound


class App():
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
        # Initialize tkinter gui attributes
        self.appName = "Hand Volume Controller"
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title(self.appName)
        self.window.resizable(0,0) # Setting window to not resizeable
        self.window.wm_iconbitmap("images-sounds/hand_icon.ico")
        self.window["bg"] = 'black'
        self.click_sound = "images-sounds/clicks.wav"
        
        self.vid = HandVolumeController(video_source)
        
        self.label = Label(self.window, text=self.appName, font=14, bg="blue", fg="white",).pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH)
        
        # Button that lets user to see fps
        self.btn_fps = Button(self.window, text="Frames Per Second tracker", width=30, bg="goldenrod2", activebackground="red", command=self.__fps_tracker)
        self.btn_fps.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=True)
    
    def __fps_tracker(self):
        playsound(self.click_sound)
        pass
    
    def __startDetection(self):
        self.vid.handDetection()
    
    # Method to run the tkinter main   
    def run_app(self):
        # Start the hand detection
        self.__startDetection()
        self.window.mainloop() # Keep window open
        return
            

class HandVolumeController():
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
        
        # Open the video source and check its valid
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.cap.isOpened():
            raise ValueError(f"> Unable to open your current video source {video_source}\n> Please try another")
        
        # Set the size of the cam
        CAM_WIDTH, CAM_HEIGHT = 640, 480
        self.cap.set(3, CAM_WIDTH)
        self.cap.set(4, CAM_HEIGHT)

        # We will change default of detection confidence to 0.7 to reduce flickering,
        # by ensuring the object we are looking hand is actually a hand
        self.detector = htm.HandDetector(minDetectionConfidence=0.7)
        
        # Fps counter vars
        self.prevTime = 0
        self.currTime = 0

        # General code to access device speakers and be able to control volume
        self.devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
        self.interface = self.devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
        self.volume = cast(self.interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))

        # print(volume.GetVolumeRange()) # == (-96.0, 0.0, 0.125)
        self.volRange = self.volume.GetVolumeRange()
        self.minVolRange = self.volRange[0]
        self.maxVolRange =  self.volRange[1]


    def handDetection(self):
        
        counter = 0 # Muting tracker
        
        while True:
            success, img = self.cap.read()
            
            img = self.detector.findHands(img)
            landMarkList = self.detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)
            
            if len(landMarkList) != 0:
                #print(landMarkList[4], landMarkList[8])
                
                # Getting the central position of thumb and index finger 
                # e.g landMarkList (thumb) = [4,480,151] 480 = x val, 151 = y val similar case for index finger tip
                x1, y1 = landMarkList[4][1], landMarkList[4][2] # Thumb tip
                x2, y2 = landMarkList[8][1], landMarkList[8][2] # Index finger tip
                cx, cy = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2 # Get the centre of the line between thumb and index
                
                cv2.circle(img, (x1,y1), 8, (0, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.circle(img, (x2,y2), 8, (0, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 255), 1) # Line between thumb and index
                cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy), 7, (255, 0 , 255))
                
                # The formula to find distance of a line between 2 points
                # You can also do math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1), but thats boring :(
                length = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
                
                if length <= 25: # Smallest volume point e.g 0 volume
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 7, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                    counter+=1
                    if counter == 50: # Roughly a 4 second delay before muting
                        self.volume.SetMute(1, None)
                elif length >= 250: # Largest volume point e.g 100 volume
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 7, (0, 0 , 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if self.detector.results.multi_hand_landmarks is not None: # Detects if there is 2 hands present
                    if len(self.detector.results.multi_hand_landmarks) == 2:
                        counter = 0
                        self.volume.SetMute(0, None)
                        
                
                # Hand range 20 - 250 & Volume Range -96 - 0
                # This code helps convert our hand range to vol range so its universal
                self.vol = np.interp(length, [25, 250], [self.minVolRange, self.maxVolRange])
                
                self.volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(self.vol, None)

                # Make a graphical volume bar, need to convert our hand range to vol bar
                cv2.rectangle(img, (50, 90), (85, 400), (0,255,0), 2)
                barVol = np.interp(length, [25, 250], [400, 90])
                cv2.rectangle(img, (50, int(barVol)), (85, 400), (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)
                
                # Convert hand range to 0 - 100 for a percentage display
                percentageVol = np.interp(length, [25, 250], [0, 100])
                cv2.putText(img, f"{int(percentageVol)}%", (50, 420), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,255), 1)
            

            # fps counter
            self.currTime = time.time()
            fps = 1/(self.currTime - self.prevTime)
            self.prevTime = self.currTime
            
            # Display counter and set location, font, size, colour and thickness
            cv2.putText(img, f"Frames Per Second (fps): {int(fps)}", (10,23), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,255), 1)
            cv2.imshow("img", img)
            cv2.waitKey(1) # 1 millisecond delay
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.run_app()
```

Comment: I know this is going to be hard but is it possible to create a minimal working example that you can post on here? It's hard to debug a whole project. Also why did you include the `tk` tag?

Comment: @TheLizzard the project is honestly just 2 files the HandTrackingModule.py and the handVolumeControl.py which is the main file, as if you mean the Tk() i thought thats how you initialize the tkinter? I have also uploaded all of the main file into the question for you

Comment: @TheLizzard my opencv camera and code seems to work as expected but when i clicked the fps tracker button on the tkinter gui, it doesnt click and when i click again it freezes and gives the error i said in the question.

Comment: I meant the `tk` tag that you added to the question. Right now the tags on the question are: `python`, `opencv`, `tkinter`, `tk`, and `gil`

Comment: oh i just thought it was short for tkinter

Comment: You need to use either multithreading or multiprocessing depending on your need. You simply cannot have a loop that runs forever along with the GUI loop.

Comment: @Art Can you tell me how i would do either whatever is easier, please thanks

Comment: @ericbailey101 There are already a lot of examples online for this. Just search multithreading/multiprocessing with tkinter. see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multithreading+tkinter) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing+tkinter).